# Is there a fast way to rotate an image with a single bright pixel?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I need to rotate a large number of images where only one pixel in the image is non-zero. To do this, I've simple been using skimage.transform.rotate. This seems like a very inefficient way to get the information I need since most pixels in the rotated image are trivially zero. What I'd like to do is apply the affine transformation to the one non-zero pixel and use the inverse transform to perform bi-linear interpolation and output the resulting coordinates/values. Is there any image processing library with built-in functions to perform these operations?

Comment: Questions asking for a library recommendation are off-topic here, see [help/on-topic]. Since you have this tagged with opencv, that would seem a decent enough choice (along with numpy that the Python bindings use), so perhaps re-phrase the question to ask "how to do this in opencv". | `cv2.findNonZero` or a numpy equivalent to find the coordinates of that one pixel. `cv2.transform` to apply the affine transform, although given how trivial a calculation that is for one point, you can just do it directly.

Comment: You can apply a sparse transformation operator, as shown [Ch 5 of Elegant SciPy](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=626bbfa8d2bbb13f4ce5c959a4a89ca99d7ba6de&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f656c6567616e742d73636970792f6e6f7465626f6f6b732f363236626266613864326262623133663463653563393539613461383963613939643762613664652f6e6f7465626f6f6b732f6368352e6970796e62&nwo=elegant-scipy%2Fnotebooks&path=notebooks%2Fch5.ipynb#Applications-of-sparse-matrices:-image-transformations) under Image Transformations.